# HTML form spanning UL

Tags: html, forms

I have a form that spans across multiple list items in an unordered list. Each list item is seen as separate "page", but isn't really. I have a long horizontal unordered list with each list item being next to the other in inline-block format. Each "page" has a "next" button, that when you click, it moves the margin over so the next "page" is visible. There's a viewport that allows you to see only 1 page at a time.  At the very end there is a submit button. This image will clear things up:

[image]

I added input elements on each page, and it worked fine. However, at the very end, I realized that I forgot to add the form tags around the input elements. Once I added the html form tag (`<form> </form>`) the page stopped working properly. Now when I click a "next" button, the margin doesn't change, the page refreshes or reloads, and I get weird url inputs as if I made a "get" request. Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: First, you should post your code in your question. Second, it sounds like the form *is* being submitted, so the question is, are you doing anything to stop it?

Comment: It looks like the code is submitting, but the "next" button is just a regular button, not a submit button.

Comment: If you're using `<button>` elements, then that's probably it since the `<button>`'s default type is submit.

Comment: So how do I change that?

Comment: `<button type="button">...</button>`

Comment: That's it!  I'll give whoever writes it up a check mark.